# How to get code to double values (x * 2) less than 10 in an array? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm taking an online Java programming class (I'm a beginner) and I cannot figure how to correctly complete the code. I've already written what I think is to be included, however I'm missing something that would make the code work completely.

**Directions:**
Double any element's value that is less than minVal. Ex: If `minVal = 10`, then `dataPoints = {2, 12, 9, 20}` becomes `{4, 12, 18, 20}`.

```
public class StudentScores {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      final int NUM_POINTS = 4;
      int[] dataPoints = new int[NUM_POINTS];
      int minVal = 0;
      int i = 0;

      dataPoints[0] = 2;
      dataPoints[1] = 12;
      dataPoints[2] = 9;
      dataPoints[3] = 20;

      minVal = 10;
    // DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING ABOVE THIS COMMENT. ABOVE IS THE DEFAULT CODE OF ASSIGNMENT

      for (i = 0; dataPoints[i] < minVal; ++i) {
         dataPoints[i] = dataPoints[i] * 2;
      }

    // DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS COMMENT. BELOW IS DEFAULT CODE OF ASSIGNMENT
      for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; ++i) {
         System.out.print(dataPoints[i] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();

      return;
   }
}
```

I made comments of what isn't to be messed with, as I am using an online interactive book and cannot edit or change the default code. Additionally, we are working with arrays in this chapter.

I'm new to this site in the sense that I don't know the unwritten ways of stackoverflow, but I've search multiple times online to see how to double the values for an array in java but I do not get the search results I need to help me.

The error messages I get are:

```
Testing minVal = 10 and dataPoints = {2, 12, 9, 20}
Expected output:  4 12 18 20 
Your output:  4 12 9 20
```

I thought that the compiler should be able to read the lines fully to register that 9 is also less than 10 and thus should be doubled to 18, but it doesn't. What am I missing to make 9 be read as well?

Comment: Hint: your loop is evaluating `dataPoints[i] < minVal` as the condition to check whether or not to continue. That's not what you want to do. You always want to process *all* of the array, but only conditionally change things... you want to make the change **if** a condition is true.

Comment: Hint: Why don't you copy the correct loop which is provided for you?

Comment: No need to edit your question to include your final answer. Have a look at [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216722/205949) on the appropriate etiquette for answering your own question.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you for directing me to that post so I can know for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, 12 < 10 evaluates to be false and so, it goes out of loop and hence, it gives Wrong Output. Check the below code:

```
 for (i = 0; dataPoints[i] < NUM_POINTS ; ++i) {
         if(dataPoints[i] < minVal) {
         dataPoints[i] = dataPoints[i] * 2;
      }
  }
```

I looped through all elements of array and if an element is < minVal, I multiplied it by 2.

Comment: There is a constant for the Array size 'NUM_POINTS', would perhaps be cleared to use that in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The second section of the [`for` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) is the termination condition: once it evaluates to false, your loop will stop executing.

In this particular problem, you're trying to look at each value in your `dataPoints` array, and double it. This calls for the use of an index variable.

Your index variable will keep track of your position within the array as you move from left to right. Starting on the left, at index `0`, you will move right until you're at the end of the array.

`++i` takes care of incrementing your index variable each time the loop runs. This is what moves you through the array.

Your termination condition should check whether you have looked at all values in the array. Once you've gone past all the values in your array your index variable is pointing all the way at the end. And remember, as soon as the termination condition is `false` your loop will stop executing. So you want to run your code while `i` (your index variable) is less than the size of the array (`dataPoints.length`).

Once you've figured out the `for` loop bounds, simply check your conditional with an [`if-then` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) before updating the values:

```
for (i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; ++i) {
    if (dataPoints[i] < minVal) {
       dataPoints[i] = dataPoints[i] * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The combination of your assistance and others have helped me figure it out. Thank you for explaining to me what I did not understand, they really did help me.

Comment: This will double all the elements and not those less than minVal alone.

Comment: @PriyanshGoel Thanks for the fix, I missed that part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; ++i) {
    if (dataPoints[i] < minVal) {
        dataPoints[i] = (dataPoints[i] * 2);
    }
}
```